# Using Solr engine, how to pin point the result json path from a chunk data

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I have a json chunk saved into solr

```
{
  A:{
    B:[
      {
        C: {
          D: {
            **name:hello**
            ...
          },
          noise:...
        }
      },
      {
        noise:...
      }
    ],
    noise:{
      ...
        ...
          ...
    },
    noise:...
    ...
  }
}
```

Saved as flatten Json into one big chunk,
when I query as **name:hello**, it returns me the whole chunk data.

How do I find A->B[0]->C->D contains "name:hello", not other noise branches?

My result expects to show A->B[0]->C->D contains the result I queried. Is there any way that I could approach this?

Comment: Usually you don't - indexing custom JSON while retaining structure and handling which parts gets returned isn't supported as far as I know. In your case you'll probably have to index A->B->C->D as a separate [document using `split` when indexing](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html).

Comment: @MatsLindh, Thank you, I probably need to redesign this.